# Conditional Formatting based on Excel Table header

Tags: excel, header, formatting, conditional-statements

I want to highlight the cells in the month columns (C-F) if the dates in column A and B are in these month. The conditional formatting is working fine as you can see in the picture. But the formula in the conditional formatting refers to the dates in row 1. If I refer on the table headers, it stops working. The format of the table headers is DATE.

`=AND(C$1>=$A3;C$1<$B3)` is working, which refers on cells in row 1 outside the table

`=AND(C$2>=$A3;C$2<$B3)` isn't working, refering on the table headers in row 2

`=AND("Table1[@Headers]">=$A3;"Table1[@Headers]"<$B3)` also not working with structured references to the table headers

Is my structured reference wrong?

[image]

Comment: When Excel creates a table the headers are text and not numbers.  Therefore when comparing numbers to text, text is always greater than any number.  Also Conditional Formatting does not work with structured references directly, One can use INDIRECT to refer to structured references, but the Date as Text problem still remains.

Comment: You can try: `=AND(--INDIRECT("Table1[@Headers]")>=$A3;--INDIRECT("Table1[@Headers]")<$B3)` not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: I tried, but it seems to be as you said, and it is treated as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use table references in CF, but you can refer to sheet ranges as usual. In CF use formula:

```
=AND(DATEVALUE(C$1)>=$A2;DATEVALUE(C$1)<$B2)
```

[image]